# Unable to print files containing specific string in their names through Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, command-line, continuous-integration, jenkins-cli

I am trying to print the names of all files that contain "jar-with-dependencies" in their names. I wrote the below lines to do this.

```
FOR /R serviceFolder %%G IN ("*jar-with-dependencies*.jar") DO (
set jarName="%%~nG"
echo %jarName%"
)
```

When I run the below code from a bat file it runs and prints the names. But when I execute this from Jenkins, I am getting an error saying "The system cannot find the file specified." I checked the folder location from Jenkins and I am in the right folder. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

2nd attempt, still no luck :

```
FOR /R update-service %%G IN ("*jar-with-dependencies*.jar") DO (
set jarName="%%~fG"
echo "%jarName%"
)
```

3rd attempt, still the same error.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R update-service %%G IN ("*jar-with-dependencies*.jar") DO (
set "jarName=%%~fG"
echo "%jarName%"
)
```

Comment: `set "jarName=%%~fG"` as `for /R` loops through files **Recursing subfolders**  and then use double quoted `echo "%jarName%"`

Comment: Please note position of first double quote in `set "jarName=%%~fG"`. Moreover, `FOR /R` cannot cause described `The system cannot find the file specified` error message. The problem lays in percent expansion inside code block. Use [`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion&echo "!jarName!"&ENDLOCAL`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), or use script-wide `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`. Sorry that I didn't noticed it before :)

Comment: @JosefZ there's something wrong with the bracketing? When I print the name on the same line as the for loop, the name gets printed. I tried this: FOR /R Services\update-service %%i IN ("*jar-with-dependencies*.jar") DO echo "%%~fi"

Comment: Use `echo "!jarName!"` in the scope of `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`. Note `!` instead of `%` for all variables defined in the same bracketed command block.

Comment: it works thanks man! please put it as the answer, will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of most often asked questions at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) related to the [[batch-file]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R update-service %%G IN ("*jar-with-dependencies*.jar") DO (
    set "jarName=%%~fG"
    echo "!jarName!"
)
```

Reference: [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)